# From Gentoo to ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I would like to move from Gentoo to ubuntu. Is there the possibility to change without pain? I have lot of data and no way to backup it! Any hint?
I have a latitude e6400, which version of ubuntu should I install?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Change without pain ? Well, you might have to fiddle a bit with your video drivers but for the rest it should be quite painless. What drivers are you currently using for video ?

Comment: nvidia (the closed one)

Comment: Hard to make any constructive comments without even a list of partitions ... ;) maybe add that. RAM available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I persume you have your valuable data on a seperate (/home) partition ?
In that case you can migrate without pain.
The ubuntu installer will let you do the partitioning if that is your preference so you are in control which partition must be home or which partition is to be left alone.

At the moment I prefer the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version (13.10 is to me a bit too buggy/unstable but that is only my personal opinion, in other words: your milage may vary)

Considering your driver preference: Ubuntu has the closed source drivers in the standard repository which can be automagically installed and configured from within it's settings icon (found in the launcher bar).

For the rest is the driver support good to top-notch. I would say, give it a go.

Comment: actually I have all in /, that`s my pain. Any simple solution?

Comment: oops! That is painful indeed. There is no simple solution other than making a backup. The not-so-simple solution is to shrink your partition first with "gparted" to make space for what will be your root partition. This is, however, not completely without danger. Also resizing, however automatic, really could take some time.